# Why button events stop after 3rd click?

Tags: angularjs

I have this site : http://www.panelatlantik.com/foodx/index.html

For example find Number 133 and click.

You will see a new colorful button on right. Click and wait 2 sec. I will change. Click again wait 2 sec. It will change again. Great! But next clicks doesn't work. What do I do wrong ?

```
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2" ng-if="pin3.status=='Yeni'">
        <button ng-click="gYap(pin3.orderid)" style="width: 100%" class="btn btn-success">PREPARING</button>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2" ng-if="pin3.status=='Gönderildi'">
        <button ng-click="iYap(pin3.orderid)" style="width: 100%" class="btn btn-success">SENT</button>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2" ng-if="pin3.status=='İptal'">
        <button ng-click="gAl(pin3.orderid)" style="width: 100%" class="btn btn-info">CANCELLED</button>
    </td>
</tr>


    $scope.gYap = function(param){
        $http.get("php/makine.php?komut=gYap&id="+param).then(function(response) {
         $scope.gYap = response.data;}) 
         $timeout( function(){
            $scope.hepsi();
    }, 1000 );

    $timeout( function(){
        $scope.siparisgetir(param);
    }, 2000 );

         }

         $scope.iYap = function(param){
        $http.get("php/makine.php?komut=iYap&id="+param).then(function(response) {
         $scope.iYap = response.data;})  
         $timeout( function(){
            $scope.hepsi();
    }, 1000 );

    $timeout( function(){
        $scope.siparisgetir(param);
    }, 2000 ); }

         $scope.gAl = function(param){
        $http.get("php/makine.php?komut=gAl&id="+param).then(function(response) {
         $scope.gAl = response.data;})  
         $timeout( function(){
            $scope.hepsi();
    }, 1000 );

    $timeout( function(){
        $scope.siparisgetir(param);
    }, 2000 ); 
         }
```

Comment: Your console log shows many errors, you should fix them first.

Comment: I have fixed now that errors but main problems remain.

Comment: Do you really expect the internet to debug your code for you?

Comment: You need to provide the js code that you think is the problem, in this case the template is not enough to identify the problem

Comment: gAl function never works 2nd time! Others as well. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

After 3rd click I received

> v2.gYap is not a function

So I think that problem is here:

```
$scope.gYap = function(param){ //<-- here gYap is definied as function
    $http.get("php/makine.php?komut=gYap&id="+param).then(function(response) {
     $scope.gYap = response.data;}) //<-- here gYap is redefinied and its no longer function
     $timeout( function(){
        $scope.hepsi();
}, 1000 );
```